# RS310 DC power supply charging 12 volt car battery

Tags: power, dc, charge

I am trying to charge a car battery with a Rockseed RS310P power supply. I set the voltage to 14.5 V and the amps to 2.0 A but when I connect it to the battery and turn it on the current drop to a very small amount...I think it was .002 A.  The voltage on the battery was 4.5 V. Can the RS310P be used to charge a car battery like a regular battery charger? Am I doing something wrong? Thanks

Comment: Your battery has developed lead sulphate on the lead plates. The safe option is to get a new one. If you know what you are doing, raise the voltage significantly and wait until it starts to pull current. Lower your voltage back to 14.5 V and charge it normally. If you leave it at high voltage and walk away, you will boil away the water into oxygen and hydrogen gas, which is explosive. Even if you manage to charge it fully, ESR and parasitic drain may both be too high for the battery to be useful.

Answer (score 1):

The battery is likely dead and will probably not accept charge, at least not in a safe manner.

4.5V and high internal resistance are a good hints.

If you really don't need neither the battery nor the power supply in a hurry, lower the amp setting to 1/100 of the rated battery capacity (e.g. 0.5A for 50Ah battery) and leave it for a few days, **preferably with no combustive or expensive items around**.

If any of these things develop:

- distinct acidic smell
- electrolyte leak
- audible or visible electrolyte bubbling or outgasing
- voltage of less than 11.5V for more than 2-3 hours
- battery temperature rising to be hot to touch

... then disconnect the charger and dispose off the battery according to your local regulations.

Caveat: nothing of the above happenning is still not a guarantee that the battery will work.

Caveat 2: the idea of using higher voltage may speed up the process (to an unknown extent) but may also lead to one of the above unpleasant events. 16V is the absolute maximum to experiment with.